# PHP Perfil con sesiones

Tags: php

Entro con un login pero en mi perfil quiero mostrar loss datos, y necesito que sea con sesiones

```html
<p>Perfil</p>
 <label>E-mail</label>
 <input type="email" name="email" readonly>
```

Asi como también tengo un nav y quiero mostrar los datos de sesion

```js
<?php
echo "<nav><span>user: -email- <a href=\"#\">Salir</a></span></nav>"
?>
```

mi problema es que entre una pagina y otra no me guarda los datos de sesión

Comment: No es necesario gritar :-(

Comment: una disculpa, es que estoy muy estresado :(

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar a qué te refieres con esto: *Entro con un login pero en mi perfil quiero mostrar los datos de la bd, solo esos datos, no los de la tabla, y necesito que sea con sesiones*. ¿A qué datos de la BD te refieres? ¿Qué error tienes? ¿Cómo conectas al a BD? La pregunta está incompleta.

Comment: lo que pasa es que tengo un login ese me verifica que este registrado en la bd y de ahi me manda a una pagina de perfil pero en esa necesito que me despliegue el email que puse en el login, guardo la sesion pero no me sale nada

Answer (score 1):

si te refieres a que cuando el login sea exitoso quieres mostrar los datos de esta persona en alguna parte, tienes que usa la variable $_SESSION y registrar la información que tu quieres, te muestro la documentación para que puedas manipular los valores:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

No se a que te refieres con no  me guarda la session pero 2 cosas que debes de hacer:

1. Cada archivo donde vas a usar sesiones debes de declarar un session_start();
2. Asigna valores a las variables de sesion $_SESSION['email']   = 'test@gmail.com';